# getting error on validating JS functions after upgrading the karate version from 0.9.5 to 1.1.0

Tags: karate

after upgrading the karate version from 0.9.5 to 1.1.0, getting all features failed at below calls

*** call if(programId==''){read('create_program.feature')}**

> js failed:
>
> > > > > 01: if(programId=='') <<<< org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError

*** call read('classpath:utils/utils.js')**

> js failed:
>
> > > > > org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as `call if(condition)` in Karate, so if that was working in the past, it is a bug - and a behavior no longer supported.

Please carefully go through the upgrade guide: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide and make changes so that your tests are valid, and refer to the documentation if needed.

And if you are still stuck, follow this process, else no one can help you: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue